# Webserver favicon not showing up (ESP8266);

Tags: html, c++, webserver, esp8266, favicon

I'm trying to build a webserver that streams data from a HC-SRO4(generic ultrasound distance sensor). Using an ESP8266. It works mostly fine but I cant figure out why the favicon is not showing up on the server.

when I inspect the webserver I have the line

```
<pre>

     <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href='"/favicon.ico">

</pre
```

in the  section but it doesnt show up (i have tried different browsers and clearing cashe)
I'm new to HTML and woring with ESP's so im sure im doing somthing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

ESP Code:

```
//Start of program
//Liraries
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
//ssid info
const char* ssid     = "xxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxx";

WiFiServer server(80);
String header; // Current time
unsigned long currentTime = millis(); // Previous time
unsigned long previousTime = 0; 
const long timeoutTime = 2000;
//setup HC-SRO4 sensor
int EchoPin = D2;
int TrigPin = D3;
long duration;
int distance;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);   // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  
  //defining HC-SR04 Pins
  pinMode(EchoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(TrigPin, OUTPUT);
  delay (1000);
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Starting WebServer
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.begin();
}

void loop(){
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             
    Serial.println("New Client.");         
    String currentLine = "";                
    currentTime = millis();
    previousTime = currentTime;
    while (client.connected() && currentTime - previousTime <= timeoutTime) { // loop while the client's connected
      currentTime = millis();         
      if (client.available()) {             
        char c = client.read();             
        Serial.write(c);                   
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-Type: 'image/ico'");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();

            // Display the HTML web page
            client.println("<link rel='icon'" );
            client.print("type='image/x-icon'");
            client.print("href='/favicon.ico'>");
            client.println("<body style=""background-color:lightgray;"">");
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<p><span style=""\"""color: rgb(41, 105, 176);""\"""><strong><span style=""\"""font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-size: 36px;""\""">ESP8266 WebServer</span></strong></span></p>");
            client.println("<p><span style=""\"""color: rgb(41, 105, 176);""\"""><strong><span style=""\"""font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-size: 36px;""\">");  
            client.print("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            client.print(distance);
            client.print("&nbsp;CM");
            client.print("</span></strong></span></p>");
            client.println("</body></html>");
            client.println("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3'>"); //refresh page every 3 seconds
            client.println("</body></html>");
            break;
          } else {
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  
          currentLine += c; 
        }
      }
    }
    // Clear the header variable
    header = "";
    // Close the connection
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    Serial.println("");
  }
  //HC-SR04 programming 
  digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin HIGH (ACTIVE) for 10 microseconds
  digitalWrite(TrigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW);
  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(EchoPin, HIGH);
  // Calculating the distance
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  float data = distance;
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println(" cm");
}
//end of program
```

Comment: there is nothing in your code to server the file and no file system to serve it from

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow!

Where exactly did you put the file favicon.ico? The browsers cannot find it, since the ESP doesn't exactly have a filesystem like most webservers.

Instead, you could **base64 encode your icon** and store it directly in the HTML tag like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAAQEAAAEAIAAwAAAAFgAAACgAAAABAAAAAgAAAAEAIAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP//AAAAAA==" />
```

You can convert your ico file [here](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image/ico).

Make sure to properly escape your HTML into the c strings. If you enclose your string in double quotes, you have to use `\"` in the text to actually print a double quote.

For the favicon, I would suggest to split your actual HTML accross several lines using multiple `client.print` commands, because I had difficulties with long lines on the ESP8266 in the past ;)

Comment: The favicon icon is in a folder inside the sketch folder in a folder called "Data"  i did split them up. Anyways i was able to go around this by using a web-link of a favicon that was close enough to what i was looking for. I think the issue has somthing to do with where the favcon was stored  thanks for the anwser!

Comment: If you want to serve the favicon through the file system you will have to use some kind of addon in your IDE as described here: https://techtutorialsx.com/2019/03/17/esp32-arduino-http-server-serving-a-favicon/